# Split string and get numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing data from a php echo to a jquery $.get function and am trying to retrieve only the numbers using if statements. The problem I have is that with the code I am using, it is only extracting the last character in the string which I know is what pop() does. However, what I need to do is split the string after each number and extract using pop() and use that value to update.

I know that the jquery code i have posted is incorrect, but this is my first attempt at something like this. I would be grateful if someone could show me how to achieve this. Many thanks

loadActions.php

```
  $brtvsql = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE activity='Box Retrieval' AND new = '1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $brtvsql);
  $brtv_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  echo 'brtv' . ' ' . '30';

  $brtnsql = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE activity='Box Return' AND new = '1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $brtnsql);
  $brtn_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  echo 'brtn' . ' ' . $count;
```

jquery code

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.get('/domain/admin/loadActions.php', function(data) {
    var value = data;
    if (value.indexOf("brtv") >= 0) {
      var brtv = value.split(/[, ]+/).pop();
      $(".retrievals").text(brtv);
      console.log(brtv);
    }
    if (value.indexOf("brtn") >= 0) {
      var brtn = value.split(/[, ]+/).pop();
      $(".returns").text(brtn);
      console.log(brtn);
    }
  });
}, 15000);
```

This is what is being returned in inspector which is correct.

```
brtv 30brtn 0
```

Comment: I'd suggest returning JSON. Then you won't need to hack around any strings

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Could you do example please. Thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is what I tried to get him to do already ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961387/load-data-into-a-html-class/50963788#50963788

Comment: @Eddie ??? Sorry do not understand comment

Comment: I am not asking anyone to code for me I just need to know how to modify my code to achieve the result

Comment: My example in previous question showed how to turn a PHP array into JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your php code like this:

```
echo 'brtv' . ' ' . '30;';
echo 'brtn' . ' ' . $count;
```

Please, notice the semicolon after the number `30`. The the response from the server will like this:

```
brtv 30;brtn 0
```

Than on the client side, you can parse the response like this:

```js
var str = "brtv 30;brtn 0";
var data = {};
str.split(";").forEach(function(s) {
 data[s.split(" ")[0]] = s.split(" ")[1];
});

// Check the result
if(data["brtv"]) {
 console.info("brtv: %s", data["brtv"]);
}

if(data["brtv"]) {
 console.info("brtn: %s", data["brtn"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works if the data is hard-coded as you have done in your answer, but these values will always change so I need to get data from `loadActions.php`. Also what is the purpose of `%s`? Thanks

Comment: for example like this: `$brtvsql = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE activity='Box Retrieval' AND new = '1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $brtvsql);
  $brtv_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  //echo 'brtv' . ' ' . '30';
  echo 'brtv' . ' ' . $count;

  $brtnsql = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE activity='Box Return' AND new = '1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $brtnsql);
  $brtn_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  //echo 'brtn' . ' ' . $count;
  echo 'brtn' . ' ' . $count;` and output result from client side

Comment: You can change the result as you want. The client side code handles the server code you've supplied. It obvious that if you change your server code you have to change the client side code. The `%s` is just for formatting output in the browser console, telling it that the value is type of `string`.

Comment: Thanks very much for help. I am sure I can figure from here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

> Server Side code

These are the changes `$response = [];`, `$response['brtv'] = 30;`, `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and `json_encode($response);`

```
  $response = [];

  $brtvsql = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE activity='Box Retrieval' AND new = '1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $brtvsql);
  $brtv_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  //echo 'brtv' . ' ' . '30';
  $response['brtv'] = 30;

  $brtnsql = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE activity='Box Return' AND new = '1'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $brtnsql);
  $brtn_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  //echo 'brtn' . ' ' . $count;
  $response['brtn'] = $count;

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
```

Php response should be like this https://eval.in/1026851
`{"brtv":30, "brtn": 2 }` here 2 is supposed value of $count

> Javascript Side

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.get('/domain/admin/loadActions.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data.brtv);
    console.log(data.brtn);
  },'json');
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am getting no data in console.log. Also I cannot see any data being passed by php response in inspector. I tried `echo json_encode($response);` but didn;t make any difference. Thanks

Comment: did you change the php side code accordingly ? like `$response = [];`

Comment: @user1532468 i have updated my answer that you need to change in your php code.

Comment: Still nothing console.log. Can you do snippet to show it working. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 sorry, my mistake i forget to add `echo` before `json_encode($response);`, changes it to `echo json_encode($response);` try now

Comment: Sorry about this but I am getting `undefined` in console.log Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173661/discussion-between-rkj-and-user1532468).